# Where to place constants in a WCF project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, constants

I am new to WCF, Where do I place the constants for my project?

I generally create a file with a namespace that holds all my static constants. But we cannot have static variables in WCF if the service is per-call or per-session. I don't want magic numbers in my code, I want constants that can be shared through out the project.

Thanks

Comment: why can't you use `const`? if they change per-call or -session, then they really aren't constants.

Comment: what is the problem with static readonly properties in that class that holds your values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are *really* constants, you would just put them in the relevant files with `const` keyword. Constants cannot be changed thefore they are thread safe.

If you need to change the value of a variable, then it's not a constant and you need to think who can change it. If it is a user's responsibility, then you can put variables in a .config file and read them from there. If code needs to change the variables, then you can use some locking mechanism to read/modify the values (lock, ReadWriteLock, etc).

Comment: he want to share this values 'out(side) the project' using constants is pretty bad cause they are evaluated at compilertime. This will force you to recompile all assemblies that depend on those constants if you change their value.

Comment: @Kolja Is exactly right. Using `const` forces a recompile whenever the value has to change. Something more flexible like XML configuration or settings files is the way to go here - based on the OP requirements.

Comment: @Yuck as I am reading the question right he wants to avoid magic numbers not adding configuration options. IMHO the Settings are are a overkill for this.

Comment: Settings files add one section to your config file. It's tiny. And the values are internally accessible to all parts of the project.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem** with using `const` or even classes which wrap magic numbers is that **they can't be changed without re-compiling**. You want to use a settings file. These aren't very intuitive to set up, so follow these steps. Right-click your project and choose *Properties*. Then find the *Settings* tab:

[image]

Click the hyperlink which will create a `Settings.settings` file in your project. You can then edit the values in the designer:

[image]

Values are stored in your `app.config` or `web.config` (in your case, since it's a WCF project).

Answer (score 2):

Settings files!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A Simple static Class with static read only properties should work.

```
Public static class Foo
{
    public static int Bar { get { return 1337; }}
}
```

Comment: Strange that this is your answer, when you commented on another suggestion that `const` requires recompilation when a value changes... This isn't immune to that short-coming either.

Comment: @Yuck this IS immune to the shortcoming that, `const` is evaluated by the compiler even if you use that value outside the declaring assembly. You just need to recompile the declaring assembly and not the using assemblies what would be the case if you use `const`

Comment: *You just need to recompile*... IMHO, that's still a little heavy-handed just to change a value.

Comment: The OP wanted to know how to avoid magic values in his code. Those are pretty unlikely to change often. Also if you want to use that values in more than one assembly it is impossible with our Solution, except you copy the same file over and over again.

Comment: OP says - *I want constants that can be shared through out the project.* That's **project** and not **solution**. Could be the OP misspeaking, but as it's written a settings file works just fine.